# Differences between functionality of oracle text with other oracle software products

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

What is the difference between functionality of Oracle Text compared with other Oracle products? Oracle database has good indexing capabilities so why I should I have to go for Oracle Text to perform indexing and retrieving the text?

Comment: Maybe my english is not good enough but I think your question is not clear: Oracle Text is an integrated component of an Oracle Database. Before asking for help, you should read the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/toc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this table and its data:

```
create table t23
    (id number,
     txt varchar2(4000)
     )
/
insert into t23 
select 1, 'Please read the Oracle documentation' from dual union all
select 2, 'This is some sample text' from dual union all
select 3, 'We all love Oracle database' from dual union all
select 4, 'It has so many features' from dual union all
select 5, 'What is full text search anyway?' from dual
/
```

The task is to discover all the records where the `txt` column contains the word 'Oracle'.  There are several options using standard operators.  For instance

```
select * from t23
where txt like '%Oracle%'
/
```

or

```
select * from t23
where instr(txt,'Oracle') > 0
/
```

But these queries will execute a full-table scan.  Not so much of a problem with a toy table like this, but a major pain in real life.  Building a B-tree index on `txt` won't help. because the whole string is indexed, so the index might only be useful when searching on the leading part of the string, that is `where text like 'Oracle%'` (and maybe not even then).

By contrast a Text index splits the string into tokens and indexes each occurrence of the token.

```
CREATE INDEX t23_txt_idx ON t23(txt) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

So with Text we can write a query like this:

```
select * from t23
where contains(txt,'Oracle') > 0
/
```

which will execute in a performative fashion:

```
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

    PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Plan hash value: 4178983470

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                   | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |             |     1 |  2027 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T23         |     1 |  2027 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  2 |   DOMAIN INDEX              | T23_TXT_IDX |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       2 - access("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("TXT",'Oracle')>0)

    Note
    -----
       - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

    18 rows selected.

    SQL>
```

This form of indexing is suited to large amounts of free text, including documents.

The cost of Text indexes is their maintenance, which is very high and may not be transactional (and depending on the index type).  So it's important to use Text indexes sensibly, when we really need to search the contents of a string on a regular basis.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/ind.htm#1010593).

These days Oracle Text is part of the regular database.  However, I see you've tagged your question [Oracle9i].  Text was part of [Standard Edition in 9iR2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96531/ch5_edit.htm), don't know about R1.